# How do I contact a person from their summoner name in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I got a persons summoner name and tried to add them when I got home, but their friend requests were full. I was wondering if you could contact them  another way?

Answer (score 3):

There is no other way to message another player without first having them on your contact list; This is to prevent harassment.